# Design pattern for an tool with common and changed fields

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am thinking for design pattern for automated testing one of tool.
It is changing based on some type chosen saving some common fields for all types.

For example:
Type 'A' chosen:

- Unique_field_for_A_01
- Unique_field_for_A_02
- Unique_field_for_A_03
- Common_field_01
- Common_field_02
- Common_field_03

Type 'B' chosen:

- Unique_field_for_B_01
- Unique_field_for_B_02
- Common_field_01
- Common_field_02
- Common_field_03

Type 'C' chosen:

- Unique_field_for_C_01
- Unique_field_for_C_02
- Unique_field_for_A_01
- Unique_field_for_B_01
- Common_field_01
- Common_field_02
- Common_field_03

The problem:

1. there are 10-40 unique fields for some types, with 30 fields always common
2. some types have intersected fields with other types (like 'Unique_field_for_A_01', 'Unique_field_for_B_01' for Type C);

I was thinking on using 'Builder' + 'Composite' but not sure if maintaining 70 fields too complex with creating multiple instances even if I group some common/unique fields in some groups?

Answer (score 1):

The idea of using builder + composite patterns looks good. But, if the objects have 30-70 fields, they have to be be broken down into smaller objects first. Here is a source that may help you: https://refactoring.guru/extract-class